# i recently changed from selenium RC to WebDriver can any suggest best alternative for getEval function?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

`return super.getEval(script);`

i want to return the string after executing the java script

(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) this).executeScript(jsExpression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
public void trigger(String script, WebElement element) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, element);
}

public Object trigger(String script) {
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
}
```

Use it:

```
 //get value
 String script = "return document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;";
 //get text
 String script = "return document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;";
 Object elementValue = trigger(script);
 String value = (String) elementValue;

 //use some element
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("someId"));
 trigger("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: What error did you receive? or you got empty string?

Comment: yes i got empty string. i mean i am not able to get the text in the code but if it contains value parameter i am getting that context otherwise empty string

Comment: <input id="tempid">testing the test</input>   for this i am getting empty string 
<input id="tempid" value="abcdefg">testing the test</input> for this i am getting abcdef

Comment: <input id="tempid">testing the test</input>
wrong using input
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Note: The <input> element is empty, it contains attributes only.

chrome is auto correcting it, from <input id="tempid">testing the test</input> to <input id="tempid"/>testing the test .... In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag, your text is out from input, try to get text through parent of this input

Comment: Replace input with p now tell me the solution please

Comment: <p id="tempid">testing the test</input> for this i am getting empty string

Comment: maybe is <p id="tempid">testing the test</p>, try to change from .value; to .innerHTML;